# Updating Excel sheet with information from a DataTable

Tags: performance, .net, excel, vb.net, com

Basically, I'm trying to update an excel sheet using a `DataTable` (*The columns structure between the two are **not** the same*) with respect to the following rules:

- Whenever an item is matched (by the product code), update a few column values.
- Whenever an item is missing in the DataTable, mark it as 'removed' (change one column in the sheet).
- Whenever an item is missing in the sheet, add it using the DataTable.

Using the following code *with 18k+ records in the DataTable, and 43k+ rows in the Excel sheet*, it takes over 15 minutes to finish updating which is too long.

Here's my current code:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateSheet(productsDT As DataTable, sheetPath As String)
    'Indices variables are retrieved from another class.
    'The following is just for clarification:

    'pCodeColIndex = 1    | barCodeColIndex = 2 | dealerPriceColIndex = 3 | titleColIndex = 4
    'endDateColIndex = 5  | srpColIndex = 6     | statusColIndex = 7      | stockColIndex = 8
    'newStockColIndex = 9 | discColIndex = 12   | categColIndex = 13      | formatColIndex = 14
    'genreColIndex = 15   | priceColIndex = 16  | newPriceColIndex = 17   | newItemColIndex = 29
    'RemovedItemColIndex = 30

    Dim dummyXlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    dummyXlApp.Quit()

    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = Nothing

    Try
        xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sheetPath)
        xlsheet = xlWb.Worksheets(1)

        With xlsheet
            Dim lastRow As Integer = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To lastRow
                Dim rngPCode As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, pCodeColIndex)
                Dim pCode As String = rngPCode.Value.ToString()
                Dim foundRow As DataRow = productsDT.Rows.Find(pCode)
                If foundRow Is Nothing Then
                    'Item doesn't exist in the DataTable, hence mark as removed.
                    Dim rngRemoved As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, RemovedItemColIndex)
                    rngRemoved.Value = 1
                Else
                    Dim rngStatus As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, statusColIndex)
                    Dim rngStock As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, stockColIndex)
                    Dim rngNewStock As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, newStockColIndex)
                    Dim rngPrice As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, priceColIndex)
                    Dim rngNewPrice As Excel.Range = .Cells(i, newPriceColIndex)

                    rngStatus.Value = foundRow.Item(6)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rngNewStock.Value) Then
                        rngStock.Value = rngNewStock.Value
                    End If
                    rngNewStock.Value = foundRow.Item(7)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rngNewPrice.Value) Then
                        rngPrice.Value = rngNewPrice.Value
                    End If
                    rngNewPrice.Value = foundRow.Item(8)

                    productsDT.Rows.Remove(foundRow)
                End If
            Next

            Console.WriteLine(productsDT.Rows.Count)
            For Each row As DataRow In productsDT.Rows
                Dim rngPCode As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, pCodeColIndex)
                Dim rngBarcode As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, barcodeColIndex)
                Dim rngDealerPrice As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, dealerPriceColIndex)
                Dim rngTitle As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, titleColIndex)
                Dim rngEndDate As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, endDateColIndex)
                Dim rngSRP As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, srpColIndex)
                Dim rngStatus As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, statusColIndex)
                Dim rngStock As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, stockColIndex)
                Dim rngPrice As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, priceColIndex)
                Dim rngDisc As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, discColIndex)
                Dim rngCateg As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, categColIndex)
                Dim rngFormat As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, formatColIndex)
                Dim rngGenre As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, genreColIndex)
                Dim rngNewItem As Excel.Range = .Cells(lastRow + 1, newItemColIndex)
                rngPCode.Value = row.Item(0)
                rngBarcode.Value = row.Item(1)
                '
                '
                'etc
                lastRow += 1
            Next
        End With

        xlWb.Save()
    Catch ex As Exception When False
        'TODO: Report
    Finally
        Try
            xlWb.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now, I know that I should minimize the number of times I make calls to a COM object (e.g 'Excel.Range`), and there's a very popular approach of creating a two-dimensional array, load all the values to it at once when retrieving data, and then set it to a range when saving values after modifications.

Well, I believe I could do that when retrieving the values. However, I *probably* won't be able to do that and set the values of all range at once because some of the columns values are formulas calculations.

*Note: Although some of the columns include formulas, I didn't set the `xlApp.Calculations` to manual in this code, because the values changed by this code doesn't affect the calculations, and I've tried that anyway and it didn't make any difference.*

Any suggestions of how to optimize this code to increase performance?

Side note: Although my code is in VB, any answer with C# code is welcomed.